# How to choose limit prices on IR futures when targeting a specific 2s10s spread?

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, futures, trading, bond-futures

I understand the concept of DV01s and when doing an interest rate future trade I need to use about a 2:1 ratio when trying to trade the 2s10s.  This is explained here:

https://www.cmegroup.com/education/whitepapers/trading-the-treasury-yield-curve.html

What I don't get is what prices on the futures I should use if I am trying to get a specific spread.  Right now as I type this the 2s10s spread from USYC2Y10 on Bloomberg is -29.  I could just buy 2 year futures and sell 10 year futures at roughly a 2 to 1 ratio.  But How do I know that I'm getting that spread of -29 bps with my trade?  When I pull up the yield on TY2 Comdty I get 4.72, and when I pull up the yield on UXYZ2 Comdty I get 4.19 for a spread of -53 bps!

I know that the CME has a prepackaged product to trade this, but if I wanted to trade futures how would I do this correctly?

Comment: The problem is USYC2Y10 is based on the yields of two specific bonds, but the futures are not based on those specific bonds (but instead the 2 cheapest from 2 baskets of bonds). So those are actually two different trades. The futures trade will only approximate the result from the bond trade.

Comment: @nbbo2 That makes sense...do people not put this trade on this way because of the approximation?  What is the best way to put on this trade aside from buying and selling the bonds (which takes a lot of capital to put on).  I thought futures would be best because its easy to put on with little capital.

Comment: It is fine to do it with futures, but resulting P&L will be somewhat different, that's all.